# Roles Required for Provisioning AppEngine to GTM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-tag-manager, roles

I am aware that in order to use the GTM server container, I need to provision (connect and link) with GCP's AppEngine.

When provisioning, the "AppEngine administrator" role alone caused an error, so I tried using the basic role "editor" and it worked.

I would like to apply a role with minimum privileges if possible, do you know of any?

Comment: To which account you assigned the `App Engine Administrator` and the `Editor` role?

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of roles and its a pain to keep track of all of them and what each role does.  I use google documents [1], [2] to assign roles, these are the roles available and what each role does.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#access-approval-roles

[2] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles